# Advice on how to overcome obstacles in studying Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation, advice

I am studying math as an undergraduate, and I have run into a problem that seems to common among students- I enjoy analysis, followed by topology, and find the topics intuitive. However, the road has been a bit bumpy with Abstract Algebra.Unfortunately, I would also like to take higher level classes in Abstract Algebra; because when I do get something (after a lot of hard work), it's very rewarding. I also don't want to feel apprehensive toward topics that involve algebra in the future.

So, while my undergrad Abstract Algebra sequence had some of my favorite classes as an undergrad, it was also frustrating, extremely time consuming, and nerve wracking. I figured that there had to be something wrong with my approach to studying; and I asked a lot of peers and TAs for tips, but didn't find advice that works for me. I try to  I have noticed a few key things that are preventing me from processing concepts more quickly:

1. I seem process information better through symbolic notation, as opposed to words. For example, if I read "2 plus 2 equals 4," I automatically have to translate this into "2 + 2 = 4." Symbolic notation is used a lot in analysis, logic, etc., but most algebra books are very, very wordy. Most of the time, when I read abstract algebra books, I honestly feel like I am reading something in a different language. I feel like I don't know what the words mean conceptually, that I'm not getting the semantics.
2. Definitions in Algebra tend to be high level from the beginning; as in each definition has a bunch of embedded definitions. I feel like I struggle to see the whole picture because of this, especially when definitions, properties and theorems sometimes take up pages of writing. I don't know how to compress these theorems into pieces that are more manageable, and keep track of the overarching theme of definitions and theorems.
3. Examples- Often, I only begin to understand definitions when I have an example that I can play with. I really enjoyed learning about modules upon discovering that abelian groups are modules over the integers. This is opposed to other math classes, where I often get a sense of the implications of a definition/theorem before seeing an example.
4. Conceptualizing structure- At the stage I am at, it seems like Abstract Algebra is all about defining different kinds of structure. The problem is, I often just can't do this, without examples with objects that are "nice," like the integers, complex numbers, fields of characteristic p, etc. Because of this, I tend to think of different structures in algebra as categories of different properties, without really putting these properties together into an intuitive structure. 
   The best analogy I can make is this: if you are a very visual person, and need to see a concrete visual representation of a structure to understand it. Then, you probably translate information into a visual form. But there are some structures that are complex, and very hard to "see" everything in one picture. So, instead, you create a picture that represents each property of the structure, but this means that it is easy to miss how all those pictures work together to build the overall structure. So understanding is lost in translation.

If anyone has had a similar experiences and has found ways to overcome these problems, I would be really grateful for suggestions. I tried to be specific with the problems I am facing. Also, if I need to make improvements to this question, I would also appreciate any advice!

Comment: Your question is fine.  I mean that it's very understandable, gives context, and provides clear explication of your concern.  The only problem with posting here on main MSE, is that we really try to steer clear of giving personal advice.  It has nothing to do with the quality of your question, which is indeed high quality, but rather represents MSEs goals to stay clear of giving advice, sharing experiences.  That said, we encourage askers to meet with their advisors to share concerns one may have.  They know you much better than we do.  Consider also consulting trusted professors you've had.

Comment: Explore as many general algebra texts as possible to see what they have in common. That doesn't mean you read them all, you just compare them topic by topic, whatever you are currently studying. Do lots of exercises. It's the same for getting good at any subject.  FWIW I think this attraction to notation is a phase that some people go through. Really in the end when you get interested ina subject, things tend to words more because they are easier to have a conversation with.

Comment: 1 and 2 seem like non-issues that are mainly in your head. These are going to pass if you stick with it. I don't understand why 3 is listed as preventing you from processing things. 4 is a valid concern, but also one that will disssappear as your confidence grows.

Comment: One challenge involved with 1) is a "vocabulary problem". This happens in a lot of technical disciplines. A bunch of new terms are often defined or discussed in terms of each other. Advice I've heard and follow on this is to recognize the problem happens and expect to have to make multiple attempts to get comfortable with the terms. The phrase "immerse yourself in the language" may be helpful. Part of the benefit of expecting to run into this is to reduce anxiety, frustration, etc. 2) is similar. The goal is to discern the gestalt from bits of information. Again expecting this obstacle helps.

Comment: Abstract algebra was my only "C" grade ever. I realized years later that my specific problem was a patchy understanding of set theory. Reading Paul Halmos' "Naïve set theory" was an epiphany--all of a sudden the ideas in algebra *made sense!* I don't know if this is contributing to your specific challenges, but I sure wish someone had told me!

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses! It wasn't clear to me from the guidelines on MSE's position on questions that ask for personal advice, so I will keep that in mind for the future. I did talk to a lot of people (professors, TAs, peers) about advice and still felt a bit lost. Now that I wrote down my concerns clearly (hopefully), I will try asking them again. Are there any online communities where a question like this would be appropriate, for future reference?

Comment: rschwieb, Xpw- In general, I have more experience in areas in areas that depend more symbolic notation, diagrams, formulas, so I am not used to expressing concepts in terms of words. I realize that fixing this requires practice. I have primarily used Dummit and Foote, and have looked at Atiyah&MacDonald, Lang, and Matsumura. I am having trouble finding solutions to the advanced questions in D&F, and in the other books (aside from online homework solutions). Working through solutions often helps me see how to describe arguments when learning a topic, so that might be a part of the problem.

Comment: SZN- thank you for the suggestion! I will have a look; hopefully that will help me understand the underlying structures. It's true that I haven't learned much set theory :)

Comment: Although your question was put "on hold" for being off-topic, I encourage you to keep asking questions here because I noted that you provide a good context, have very clear what is your concern and also you have a nice wording.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your experiences are very common.  Kudos for raising these concerns.  Let me respond to your points, by the number, and not in the order in which you gave them.:)

Point #3  Everyone begins to understand only after acquiring a certain empiricism (studying examples).  Mathematics is as experimental as other sciences, opined several mathematicians, including P. Halmos and V. Arnold ("On teaching mathematics").  In his "Lectures on PDE", Arnold says that one's knowledge is nothing more than the collection of examples one has understood thoroughly and completely.  So, don't be surprised or alarmed: you are being human.:)

Point #1  This is probably an illusion.  Yes, $2+3=5$ reads better in notation than in prose, but slightly more advanced material will reveal the opposite pattern.  For example, which definition of continuity of a function $f(x)$ at $x=a$ do you find more palatable (think back to when you first saw this):

the notational definition
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 : |a - x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(a) - f(x)| < \epsilon,
$$
or the prosaic definition: *into every neighborhood of $f(a)$ the function $f$ maps some neighborhood of $a$*?

As a byproduct, note that the latter definition continues to hold even in the most general setting, when $f$ acts from one topological space to another, hence illustrating how topological spaces are a generalization of the metric ones.

Points ## 2 and 4:  I would recommend the following phases (which, unfortunately, may conflict with your university's course offerings, so consider taking academic leave for self-study, it's cheaper:).

First, get a good background on groups (not only what they "are", but also what they are for).  Your criterion of having "gotten there": you can clearly connect the concept of a group to: (i) symmetry, and (ii) conservation laws.  Literature: First part of "Abel's Theorem in Problems and Solutions" by Alekseev, and the relevant chapters of "Ordinary Differential Equations" by V. Arnol'd.  Arnol'd's dictum: there are no other groups except groups of transformations of a set.  (Granted, the set can have a complicated structure, and it can be of interest whether the group breaks that structure.)

Second, to make finite groups completely geometric and "unabstract", the first 40 pages of Serre's "Linear representations of finite groups".  I said "geometric" and not "visual", because the representation spaces generally have dimension above 4, hence cannot be visualized, but with a good grasp of linear algebra, these two should be identical.:)

Why do we need rings and algebras?  One use is to understand the structure of polynomials, and these do arise in analysis (including analysis on manifolds).  See page 1 of {https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/papers/arn.pdf}  A good source on commutative rings: Atiyah & McDonald's "Commutative algebra".  Also, Lie algebras arise in geometry (since you already plan to read Arnol'd's "ODE":), you will see those).

You are right to seek physical and technical examples for mathematical concepts.  Hope this is helpful, and good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’ll have to look up “Lecture’s on PDE.” And thanks for the example on notational definition. On first glance, I still find the first notational definition more comfortable, but I see what you mean regarding language being easier to generalize. I’ll try to take that perspective in the future. 
I am looking forward to going over the papers and books that you suggested. I have looked at Atiyah and MacDonald, but I hadn’t heard of the other pieces previously. Thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you for share your (empirical) point of view. This kind of answers are really gold. I think that math.stackexchange would change it policy about "opinion-based" answers for some kind of questions.

Comment: Thank you.  Glad to contribute.